# カート画面のセレクトボックスをテキストボックスに変更したい

Tags: php, html

今はこういう状態ですが

```
$body .= '<select name="number" id="';
//コンボボックス内容が変えた時　onchangeのfunctionが実行
$body .= $row["ID"] . '" onchange="changeNumber( this );"  >';
//数量を数値に変換する
$qty = (int) $row["quantity"];

for ($number = 0; $number <= 10; $number++) {
    $body .= '<option ';

    if ($number == $qty) {
        $body .= ' selected value="' . $number . '">' . $number . '</option>';
    } else {
        $body .= ' value="' . $number . '">' . $number . '</option>';
    }
}

$body .= '</select>';
```

`input type="text" name=number value="??"`がわかりません。。。。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: テキストボックスのinput のvalue内容がどうすればいいのかわからないです

Answer (score 0):

余談ですが、HTMLではコンボボックスではなく「セレクトボックス」と呼ぶことの方が多いと思います。

---

既存のコードだと`<select>`で選択肢を選ばせていますが、これをテキストボックスでの任意入力にさせたいということであれば、以下のHTMLを出力するようにすればよさそうです。

```
<input type="text" name="number">
```

表示されたHTMLに入力された値が`value`として送信されるので、HTMLを出力するタイミングでは
`<input type="text" value="...">`のような指定は必要ありません。